# Question solved but solution not available for disclosure, how to proceed?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

I did a follow up this morning to a question from last year for which I was curious what could have happened as it was silent.

Through the comment section I inquired the person that ask to provide an update, basically the answer was that someone had been payed to solve it and that the changes done to fix it were not available.

At this point the issue has been solved by third party but question remains open, therefore I have a couple of concerns:

1. Can I post as an answer that it was solved by a third party (I know this is lame, but the idea is to not leave it unresolved/unanswered).
2. Which takes me to my next question, how to proceed with this question which is basically a dead end, or if someone else has to handle (i.e someone else with further privileges/rights)
3. Or should I even suggest the question owner to close it/ post solved by himself.

For sake of argument, I did a follow up around 6 months after initial post so it is unlikely (take that with a grain of salt) someone will fill around with the correct solution.

Short research I did is below, so if this question is duplicate sorry in advance:

Some of the links I researched, yet they were not what I was looking for>

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment
- [How to handle the 'nevermind, I figured it out' comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86748/how-to-handle-the-nevermind-i-figured-it-out-comments)

Additionally read briefly over>

- https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

The specific issue I'm referring about is [Sonicwall with BGP unable to route to AWS VPN](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/sonicwall-with-bgp-unable-to-route-to-aws-vpn?noredirect=1#comment79300_41776) in case you would like to do some checking.

Comment: @TeunVink sorry, I have deleted comments, thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with leaving a question unanswered if there is no explanation what has been done to resolve the problem.

Posting an answer that it was solved but the poster doesn't know how won't help much. There's no real benefit for others looking to solve similar problems, and only the person posting the question is able to accept an answer, so the question would remain unresolved. You can consider adding this as a comment for others to see though.

Moderator's can't accept answers, so the only real way to close the question is to vote to close the question, possibly with reason "unclear what you're asking". However, given the amount information and discussion I think that's a bit unfair.

Personally, I wouldn't be bothered, and just leave this question for what it is. Maybe someday someone has something useful to add to it, or maybe someone with similar problems may be helped with the discussion. If not, it's just another unanswered question. Which is unfortunate and a bit unwanted, but it's not uncommon on any Stack Exchange site.